# Array values by function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Just a two part question about PHP Arrays (I've read through the comments on php.net, but couldn't see any mention of how this might work.)

Can I have an array populated with functions? For example, using Wordpress:

```
$arr = array(blog_info('name'), blog_info('stylesheet_url'));
```

and if so, are these functions called only when $arr[0] or $arr[1] is called, or once the script reaches the array?

Comment: use `array_map()` or `array_walk()`

Comment: The WordPress function doesn't have an underscore in its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions are executed as soon as the line containing them is executed. So the array will contain the return values of those two functions.

Using PHP5.3 you could store anonymous functions in it which could be called later:

```
$arr = array(function() {
    return blog_info('name');
}, function() {
    return blog_info('stylesheet_url');
});
```

Then you could call `$arr[0]()` and `$arr[1]()` later.

Comment: Very cool. Would create_function be similar for compatibility before 5.3?

Comment: Yes. But since you pass the function body as a string it's extremely ugly.

Comment: True. Unfortunately I will have to live with it, since I can't guarantee the users will all be on 5.3. Thanks for your help!